# Importing a .sql into a new database

Tags: mysql, sqlite, phpmyadmin

I'm new to MySQL and SQL. I had an old SQLite database on a server for a game. I extracted the contents into multiple .sql files. I then managed to get them into one big .sql.

When I go to import the .sql file into a new database (which I have done nothing to) I get this error:

http://prntscr.com/7tghe2

Comment: Remove the " " from around the table name

Comment: Also you may run in to other database-specific differences when trying to run your script on a different database (datatype differences, etc).

Comment: Ok I removed the " " from on of the files to test. It then said 'table name doesn't exist. My next question is, how do I know how many columns to put?

Comment: What columns? Where? and why is this tagged sql-server? You only mentioned SQLite and MySQL.

Comment: Huh? Having followed someones steps, Im now being asked to create a table for it. But in order to create I table I have to enter an amount of columns. I don't know how many columns to set it to?

Comment: Munch, I deleted the tag that was originally in your question that said sql-server ... @underscore_d. That tag caused some confusion

Comment: If you don't know which columns to put in your table, how on Earth would _we_?